# I am trying to make a simple taxi fare estimator code

Tags: python

```
#Computes and outputs travel time
#For a given speed and distance
#Written by Emele Lasaqa 10/10/19

location = input("Enter your location in longitude and latitude: ")
location= int(location)
distance = input("Enter your distance in miles: ")
distance = float(distance)

time = distance/speed

print("At", location, "location latitude location longitude, it will take")
print(time, "hours to travel", distance, "miles.")

input("\n\nPress the Enter ket to exit"
```

I am constructing a code that calculates the taxi fare from one location to the other and the 
distance it takes. But i keep getting this error! Can someone help me out?

```
**This is the OUTPUT**

Enter your location in longitude and latitude: 18.1489° S, 178.4474° E

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/acer/Desktop/Distance - location calculator.py", line 5, in <module> 

location = input("Enter your location in longitude and latitude: ") 

File "<string>", line 1 

18.1489° S, 178.4474° E 
   ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>>
```

Comment: You're trying to write Python 3 code on Python 2. Get Python 3.

Comment: okay thanks! Its actually the first time ill use Python 3

Comment: Is it python 3.5.7?

Comment: Can you make the title of the question better reflect the question itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your location is a string, so it cannot be converted to int. You don't seem to use it anyway. You don't provide speed either.
it would make more sense if it was:

```
speed = input("Enter your speed: ")
speed = int(speed)
distance = input("Enter your distance in miles: ")
distance = float(distance)

time = distance / speed # works in python 3, if not cast as float
print(f"At {speed} it will take")
print(f"{time} hours to travel {distance} miles.")
```

you had a few errors in your script:

- undefined variables
- trying to parse a string as an int (I would recommend asking the user to enter latitude, then longitude, and cast them as floats)
- the print function takes only one argument, the preferred method in python 3 is format strings.